# Should we allow anonymous questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

A lot of people are likely to have embarrassing health issues that mean they want to ask the questions anonymously, rather than under their main Stack Exchange account.

Now, I strongly suspect this will be rejected by Stack Exchange, but I just thought I'd give them this choice:

- Allow anonymous questions through some proper mechanism
- Have a ton of people create sockpuppet accounts to be able to ask anonymously

If it were me, I'd want my site to have a proper anonymous mechanism and avoid a bunch of duplicate accounts.  But nevertheless, one of these two options WILL happen.

Comment: Interesting point. I hadn't thought about that aspect of it. I suspect you are right, that it will lead to some sock puppetry, but probably not with the intention of being deliberately harassing. Something to think about, though.

Comment: I have requested on many, many occasions that we allow users to disassociated an account from their "professional" presence on the network (essentially making them *anonymous*), but they have always been rejected.

Answer (score 3):

To be fair this is a issue on a lot of other sites as well where people ask questions that they don't want linked to their main account. If that is an issue then they can just create an alternate account that is not connected to their main account and anonymous. This does pop up from time to time on Stack Overflow where people ask a simple or homework question and later want it dissociated from their account or just plain create a new account to ask the question.

Not only that with the new user profile you have the option of hiding communities which for the most part will make your activity on them hidden from your profile.